# Git branch switch automatically issue

Tags: git, github, branch

I have came across this strange behaviour my git branch changes automatically to a local branch..

see below when i do git status i see it has moved back to local-v2.0. What is the reason---

C:\BBB-FEO\GIT_REPO\ecom-appconfigsvc>git status
On branch dev02-v2.0
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/dev02-v2.0'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

C:\BBB-FEO\GIT_REPO\ecom-appconfigsvc>git status
On branch local-v2.0
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/local-v2.0'.

### nothing to commit, working tree clean

C:\BBB-FEO\GIT_REPO\ecom-appconfigsvc>

Comment: A couple of screenshots would be much appreciated, it's hard to follow this

Comment: You’re not switching branches.

Comment: the issue was with config server  pulling after a period from the git...and thus switching branches